# Ajax post return error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

When I post to my asmx web service, this error is returned:

> Could not create type 'myProjectName.AutoCompleteWebService'.

I tried all answers in StackOverflow and many other sites, but none one working in my case.

**JQuery**

```
$("#txtSearchKeyWord").autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
       $.ajax({
          url: "AutoCompleteWebService.asmx/IndentifySearch",
          data: "{ 'keyWord': '" + request.term + "','Lang': 'En' }",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
          success: function (data) {
                 $(currentElement).css({ "background": "rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box" });
                 response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                     return {
                        value: item
                     }
                 }))
          },
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
          }
       });
  },
  open: function (event, ui) {
       //$(".ui-autocomplete").css("left", (parseInt($(".ui-autocomplete").css("left").replace("px", "")) - 114).toString() + "px");
  },
  minLength: 3,
  appendTo: "#Autocontainer"
});
```

**ASMX**

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="AutoCompleteWebService.asmx.cs" Class="RoyalTours.AutoCompleteWebService" %>
```

**C#**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]

public class autocomp : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   [WebMethod]
   public List<string> IndentifySearch(string keyWord)
   {
      string currentPageURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
      List<Package> olstPackage = null;
      olstPackage = new PackageRepository().SearchPackage(keyWord);
      List<string> olstResult = null;
      if (olstPackage.Count > 0)
      {
          olstResult = new List<string>();
          for (int indexCountry = 0; indexCountry < olstPackage.Count; indexCountry++)
          {
              olstResult.Add(olstPackage[indexCountry].KeyWord);

              if (olstPackage.Count <= 0)
              {
                  olstResult.RemoveAt(indexCountry);
              }
            }
       }
       return olstResult;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd venture to guess that this is an issue of a class mismatch between your `.asmx` and `.asmx.cs` files.

On the top of your `.asmx` page, be sure that your `Class` attribute matches the `class` at the top of your `.asmx.cs` page, like so:

**Code-Behind**

```
public class myService: System.Web.Services.WebService
```

**Front end**

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="myService.asmx.cs" Class="MyProject.MyService" %>
```

It's fairly common habit if using Visual Studio to create a new Web Service (which has a default name of something like `Service1.asmx`), and then rename it to `MyService.asmx`. But it's important to note that this does *not* update the class references along with the filename, and so it can cause a headache in the event you forget.

---

**EDIT:** Went ahead and edited your question to clean up the code, only to realize you had actually included the markup for the page AND the code-behind.

Just as I suspected, your classes don't match. Take a look:

**.asmx**

```
Class="RoyalTours.AutoCompleteWebService"
```

**.asmx.cs**

```
public class autocomp
```

Comment: yes you are right I think am tired so So I did not pay attention for my class name thank you for your help this is a true answer....

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)